# DuckDB: querying csvs containing values with newlines

Tags: duckdb

According to the csv spec, values containing newlines should be wrapped in double quotes.  Spreadsheet programs generally handle this well, treating a newline within a quoted value as a single cell.

Unfortunately I haven't managed to achieve the same in DuckDb. If I try to select using read_csv_auto, upon scanning the value with a newline DuckDb will raise an error on the grounds of an unterminated double quote.

I can escape the newline by hand, e.g. \\n, but this will still resolve to \\n in query output, so I'd also need to manually unescape string-typed fields which quickly becomes a pain to maintain.  I can change the newline character, but since the only options are \n, \r, and \r\n, this only really moves the problem.

Is there a good solution here for getting back the same newlines I insert, without raising errors?

Comment: Can you provide some example records that are producing this error?